# How can I add a toolbar button to KDE titlebars?

Tags: kde, toolbar

I want to add toolbar buttons to KDE titlebars to avoid using the menu for certain tasks. As an example I want to be able to get a screen to stay on top until I disable it. eg. KDE titlebars have a menu item `More Actions -> Keep Above Others`.

How would I add a button to enable or disable it with one click?

Comment: Can you please be more specific what you mean by "KDE screens" ? Do you refer to the window titlebar?

Comment: @doktor5000 Yes, I mean the windows title bar.

Comment: That's what I assumed in the first place, see my answer below for details. If something is missing, just give me a hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution would be to assign a keyboard shortcut for that kwin action. Open [systemsettings => shortcuts and gestures](https://userbase.kde.org/System_Settings/Shortcuts_and_Gestures) and choose Global Keyboard Shortcuts in the left panel, and on the right pane select **KWin** at the **KDE component** dropdown menu.

And for the button, if you only want to trigger built-in functions, that is pretty easy to add, you can also configure that in [systemsettings => workspace appearance](https://userbase.kde.org/System_Settings/Workspace_Appearance#Window_Decorations). Click on **Configure Buttons ...** at the bottom, and enable **Use custom titlebar button positions**. Then simply drag&drop the actions to the place where you want it on the titlebar, and add spacers as needed.

[image: This is how it should look like in the end]

See also http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2012/07/04/how-to-custmize-kdes-window-titlebar-buttons/ for a detailed description with screenshots.

If you want to add custom actions, you might need to have a look into the KWin scripting facilities:

- https://techbase.kde.org/Development/Tutorials/KWin/Scripting
- https://techbase.kde.org/Development/Tutorials/KWin/Scripting/API_4.9
- [How can I run a kwin script from the command line?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115084/how-can-i-run-a-kwin-script-from-the-command-line)

If you would really want to add a custom button to the titlebar, you would need to customize or create the window decoration in an existing or new theme for that.