# wmctrl-like tool or alternative for kde wayland

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, kde, wayland, wmctrl

A big part of my workflow is based on using shortcuts. Currently I use xbindkeys and wmctrl to run-or-raise an application. E.g: <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> brings up firefox or run it if not running.

Autokey works fine with KDE and I could also use KDE native custom shortcut manager to replace `xbindkeys` but I can't find (and I googled a lot) a way to determine if a window/application is running and if not, raise it.

I can probably use `ps` or a similar command to find if an application is running and if not, launch it, but it goes to the final problem: how to raise (or focus) an existing running window/application programmatically?

There seems to be some kind of `gdbus` solution for GNOME but of course this won't work in KDE.

Does anyone have an idea or clue of what can I do?

Answer (score 6):

After much research, I got into a solution that will only work for KDE and only KDE: using a kwin script.

The script is:

1. use `pgrep` to see if a program is running (useful command `grep`)
2. if running:

   1. install an on-the-fly kwin script that will explicitly "activate" a window with a passed className or title
   2. run the script
   3. stop the script
   4. uninstall the script
3. if not running: run a command to start it.

For example, let's say I want to focus or launch Firefox, I'd do with my script:

```
ww -f firefox -c firefox
```

`-f`: the window classname
`-c`: the command to run if not running
`-fa`: alternative filter to use the window title instead of the class

[This is the script](https://gist.github.com/academo/613c8e2caf970fabd260cfd12820bde3) I am using now and it's been working great.

Answer (score 0):

This **AutoKey** script will focus **Firefox** if it's running or launch and focus it if it's not:

```
output = system.exec_command("wmctrl -l", getOutput=True)
if "Firefox" in output:
    window.activate("Firefox",switchDesktop=True)
else:
    subprocess.Popen(["firefox"])
```

*Note that I used the **subprocess.Popen** function because it allows you to execute other code and/or interact with the process with the **subprocess.communicate** function while the process is running.*

Comment: Wmctrl is an xorg utility that doesn't work on Wayland so this won't work.