# How to run KWin script on startup, and what is installed script for if its not run at startup

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, kde, plasma, kwin

Recently I've been playing with KWin script https://develop.kde.org/docs/plasma/kwin/

I understand that I can open the IDE for creating KWin script by either:

- running command `qdbus org.kde.plasmashell /PlasmaShell org.kde.PlasmaShell.showInteractiveKWinConsole` in console
- running command `plasma-interactiveconsole --kwin` in console
- press `Alt+F2` then type `wm console` then enter

Now I've created a script like such:

```
print("registerShortcut ...");;
registerShortcut("...","...", "Meta+C", function() {
   ...
});
```

I can run it successfully on the IDE, and when it run, when I check it in `journalctl`, it add a log which print my registerShortcut string above:

```
$ journalctl -f | grep registerShortcut
Nov 12 xx:xx:xx HOST kwin_x11[1105]: js: registerShortcut ...
```

Now I have a nice shortcut of Meta+C for doing anything I specify in above function.

But I don't want to press `Alt+F2` then type `wm console` then enter, then open/load the script manually every startup, just to enable my shortcut.

So I'm looking at https://develop.kde.org/docs/plasma/kwin/#packaging-kwin-scripts in hope that if I package it then install it in my own machine then it'll be run at startup. So I placed it in ~/tools/kwin-script-1.

File ~/tools/kwin-script-1/metadata.desktop:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=kwin-script-1
Comment=kwin-script-1
Icon=preferences-system-windows

X-KDE-PluginInfo-Author=xxx
X-KDE-PluginInfo-Email=yyy@gmail.com
X-KDE-PluginInfo-Name=kwin-script-1
X-KDE-PluginInfo-Version=1.0
X-KDE-PluginInfo-License=GPL

Type=Service
X-KDE-ServiceTypes=KWin/Script
X-Plasma-API=javascript
X-Plasma-MainScript=code/main.js
```

File ~/tools/kwin-script-1/contents/code/main.js

```
print("registerShortcut ...");;
registerShortcut("...","...", "Meta+C", function() {
   ...
});
```

Then I install it with `kpackagetool5 --type=KWin/Script -i ~/tools/kwin-script-1`

But it seems all it does is just copying them to `~/.local/share/kwin/scripts/kwin-script-1/`, and it doesn't run at startup, evident by output of `journalctl -b | grep registerShortcut` is empty

So, the question is:

- how to run KWin script at startup?
- if installing the KWin script does not make it run at startup, then why bother installing at all? what's the purpose of installing them (or copying them to `~/.local/share/kwin/scripts/...`?
- I'm aware of [How can I run a kwin script from the command line?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115084/how-can-i-run-a-kwin-script-from-the-command-line) and I've tried using them (I'm thinking of adding them to my bash_profile or bashrc to automatically run it at startup): it didn't work (either running manually via console or via bash_profile/bashrc)

  - command:

```
script="/home/kristian/.local/share/kwin/scripts/kwin-script-1/contents/code/main.js"
num=$(dbus-send --print-reply --dest=org.kde.KWin \
    /Scripting org.kde.kwin.Scripting.loadScript \
    string:"$script" | awk 'END {print $2}' )
dbus-send --print-reply --dest=org.kde.KWin /$num \
    org.kde.kwin.Scripting.run
```

- output:

```
Error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownInterface: No such interface 'org.kde.kwin.Scripting' at object path '/4'
```

- command:

```
$ script="/home/kristian/.local/share/kwin/scripts/kwin-script-1/contents/code/main.js"
num=$(dbus-send --print-reply --dest=org.kde.kwin.Scripting \
    /Scripting org.kde.kwin.Scripting.loadScript \
    string:"$script" | awk 'END {print $2}' )
dbus-send --print-reply --dest=org.kde.KWin /$num \
    org.kde.kwin.Scripting.run
```

- output:

```
Error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.kde.kwin.Scripting was not provided by any .service files
Error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownInterface: No such interface 'org.kde.kwin.Scripting' at object path '/'
```

Comment: Did you make sure to not only install but also enable the script in system settings?

Comment: how do I enable it? @lemontree

Comment: Search system settings for "KWin script" and check the checckbox for the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have not only installed but also enabled the script:

System Settings > Window Management > KWin Scripts > check the checkbox for the script > Apply

or

```
kwriteconfig5 --file kwinrc --group Plugins --key nameofyourkwinscriptEnabled true
qdbus org.kde.KWin /KWin reconfigure
```

Comment: oh right, now it works, thanks; they should add it to their documentation I think