# How to run an arbitrary command from a Kwin script?

Tags: scripting, kde, d-bus, kwin

I want to run some commands when the active window changes in KDE. How can I do this from within a kwin script?

My use case is that I want to [change monitor color preset](https://gitlab.com/AndrewShark/monitor-commander) for some applications, and another use case is to [toggle input remap](https://github.com/KarsMulder/evsieve/issues/18) depending on active application.

There is a similar question: [How can I run a kwin script from the command line?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115084/how-can-i-run-a-kwin-script-from-the-command-line) But this question is not related.

Previously, I could use Window Actions for X11 to partly solve the problem, but that UI was removed (see [Bug 455444](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=455444)) as it does not work in Wayland.

I have heard that kwin scripts could not explicitly run an arbitrary commands, and the only way to interect with outside world is running dbus commands. But I am not completely sire about this statement. And if that is true, which is the dbus command, that runs an arbitrary shell command?

I tried searching, and found only few info. [Question on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/o6byep/question_about_calldbus_from_a_kwin_script/) that says that maybe dbus call to krunner can help. I think this probably is a key to solve the task. And this another [question](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/g434qq/how_can_i_run_shell_commands_in_kwin_scripts/), but it has nothing useful in answers.

Any help and code example would be appreciated.

Comment: I also did some search and found nothing. So I filed a feature request to kwin: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=474207 I'll keep this post updated.